# SQL - Trazer somente registros de 1 ano pra trás

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando realizar um SELECT que me traga somente clientes que não compram há 1 ano pra traz sem duplicar o cliente.

Abaixo o código que estou tentando:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID, p.Nome_Fantasia, v.Data from Venda v 
inner join Cliente cli on cli.ID_Pessoa = v.ID_Pessoa
inner join Pessoa p on p.ID = cli.ID_Pessoa
where Data < '2017-04-24 00:00:00.000'
order by p.ID
```

Porém, mesmo utilizando o DISTINCT, ele me traz Clientes duplicados.

Comment: Está agrupando porque alguma das colunas tem o valor diferente. Você deve usar o Group by

Comment: Se quer só os clientes, por que está usando Data no `select` com `distinct`? Vai trazer todos os registros de diferentes datas, tente remover a data do `select`

Answer (score 3):

Como já observado pelo pessoal, se você inclui a data da venda no `SELECT` o cliente aparecerá uma vez para cada venda que ele teve antes da data limite definida (1 ano atrás). Nesse caso, é necessário remover a data pura do select, mas faz sentido incluir um `GROUP BY` e um `MAX` na data para que ele te retorne a data da venda mais recente feita para este cliente.

Aproveitando, corrigi um erro de conceito na consulta. Você não deveria basear a sua consulta na venda se quiser considerar os clientes que nunca compraram (teoricamente esses caras também atendem a sua restrição). Nesse caso, o correto seria basear a consulta no `Cliente` e usar um `OUTER JOIN` para verificar as vendas.

Para tornar a consulta dinâmica, usei a função `DATEADD` para representar um ano atrás a partir da data corrente (365 passados).

Sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID, p.Nome_Fantasia, Max(v.Data) 
FROM Cliente cli 
    JOIN Pessoa p on p.ID = cli.ID_Pessoa
    LEFT JOIN Venda v on cli.ID_Pessoa = v.ID_Pessoa
WHERE v.Data  IS NULL OR v.Data < DATEADD(day, -365, GETDATE())
GROUP BY p.ID, p.Nome_Fantasia
ORDER BY p.ID
```

*Como passamos a usar um `OUTER JOIN`, é necessário contemplar a possibilidade de não ter havido venda também na cláusula `WHERE`*

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 2):

Se você precisa só do nome do cliente, pode não retornar os demais campo. Quando você traz a `data` também na consulta, o mesmo cliente com datas diferentes é retornado.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID, p.Nome_Fantasia
FROM Venda v 
INNER JOIN Cliente cli ON cli.ID_Pessoa = v.ID_Pessoa
INNER JOIN Pessoa p ON p.ID = cli.ID_Pessoa
WHERE Data < '2017-04-24 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY p.ID
```

---

Caso precise, por exemplo, da data da última compra do usuário, podes usar da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID, p.Nome_Fantasia, MAX(v.Data)
FROM Venda v 
INNER JOIN Cliente cli ON cli.ID_Pessoa = v.ID_Pessoa
INNER JOIN Pessoa p ON p.ID = cli.ID_Pessoa
WHERE Data < dateadd(year, -1, convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 120))
GROUP BY p.ID, p.Nome_Fantasia
ORDER BY p.ID
```

Assim, trará os dados do usuário "inativo" a pelo menos um ano com a data da última compra.

Detalhe: pra garantir que sua consulta sempre trará "um ano pra traz", alterei para que a data use o [`DATEADD`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

Mas qual o problema em trazer clientes duplicados? Um mesmo cliente não pode comprar mais de uma vez no mesmo dia, por exemplo?

Em todo caso, tenta usar o BETWEEN (mais performático) e o GROUP BY (para agrupar pelo ID do cliente)

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID, p.Nome_Fantasia, v.Data from Venda v 
inner join Cliente cli on cli.ID_Pessoa = v.ID_Pessoa
inner join Pessoa p on p.ID = cli.ID_Pessoa
WHERE (Data BETWEEN '2017-04-24 23:59:59' AND '2018-04-24 10:15:55')
GROUP BY cli.ID
```